# Short time token with the Graph API and Facebook login through the iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, sdk

For some players, a short-lived access token with Origin = "Web" is being issued despite the authentication process occurring through the Native iOS SDK. Furthermore, the token is not being extended and expires after approximately 1 hour, contrary to the documentation which asserts that a long-lived token will always be issued through the SDK.

Conversely, other users continue to receive a long-lived token with Origin = "Mobile Web Faceweb", with a token lifespan averaging around 2 months and automatic renewal.

We have observed that this behavior can be avoided by clearing cookies in Safari and then logging into Facebook through our application from scratch, i.e., by entering the user's Facebook login credentials. In this case, the token is always long-lived. However, on our end, we cannot adequately handle token loss as it occurs too frequently and sometimes outside of the player's session, which disrupts the gaming experience.

Steps to Reproduce:

- Attempt Facebook login through the iOS SDK.
- Observe the type and lifespan of the access token issued.
- Compare the token issued with the expected behavior outlined in the documentation.
- Note the differences in token origin and lifespan between different users.
- Attempt to mitigate the issue by clearing cookies in Safari and reattempting Facebook login.

Expected:

- A long-lived access token should be consistently issued through the iOS SDK for all users.
- Tokens should have an origin consistent with the method of authentication (Native iOS SDK).
- Tokens should have a lifespan of approximately 2 months with automatic renewal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPDzz.png)

Actual:

- Some users receive short-lived access tokens with an origin of "Web", contrary to the expected behavior.
- Tokens expire after approximately 1 hour and are not automatically renewed.
- Other users continue to receive long-lived tokens with an origin of "Mobile Web Faceweb", as expected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIBzz.png)